# If lines in txt file is 0 it should embed emoji

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm making an account gen bot with discord.js.  In this case, I need to add an emoji to embed if a text file has less than 0 (❌) this emoji. If the minecraft.txt has more than 1, I should send (✅) in the embed.

Here is the stock cmd code:

> const Discord = require('discord.js')

```
 module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, gen) => {
 let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('**Accounts In Stock**')
  .setColor(`#33FFFF`)
  gen.calculateStock()
  setTimeout(() => {
     const stock = gen.stock
    for(const type of stock) {
        embed.addField(type[0], type[1], true)
    }
    message.channel.send(embed)
    setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 10000);
 }, 200);
 
 }
 module.exports.help = {
 name: 'stock',
 aliases: []
 }
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this question. Where does the .txt file come from? I would avoid using any library like that, but that is my opinion because I don't like living inside a box someone else created. Interacting with the Discord API is a fun way to start learning programming, but not if you use libraries like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Message.React()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=react)
So just add

```
message.channel.send(embed).then(message => for(const type of stock) {
    if (type[1]<=0) {message.react('❌')} else {message.react('✅')}
}
```